# C# is writing a file in Visual Studio but not when I publish it

Tags: c#, file-io, publishing

I have the following code which is supposed to go td on each of them through a list of orgs, call the toString method on each of them, and print the result to both the console and to a file named Debug1.tab.

```
try
{
    StreamWriter print = File.CreateText("Debug1.tab");
    Console.WriteLine(LinkedInClass.isThrottled);
    int p = 1;
    foreach (Org org in orgList)
    {
        try
        {
            if (org.numContacts > 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(org.ToString());
                print.WriteLine(org.ToString());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception) {  Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace); Console.WriteLine(e.Message); Console.ReadKey();}
    }
    print.Close();
    Console.WriteLine("There were " + orgList.Count + " organizations in the list." + LinkedInClass.numWithContacts + " of which I found contacts for. Throttling was "+(LinkedInClass.isThrottled?"":"not ")+"encountered.");
    break;
}
catch (Exception e) { Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace); Console.WriteLine(e.Message); Console.ReadKey(); }
```

In Visual Studio it works perfectly but when I publish it the program doesn't create the file or write to it. It's still writing to the console, the catch statements aren't executing, and immediately after it should be closing the streamWriter it correctly prints to the console.

Comment: This is probably a rights issue. What happens if you run your published binary as administrator?

Comment: Just a guess, but you might not have write access to the program folder after it's published.

Comment: If you deploy the app in a folder under Program Files, the app might not have the rights to write to the folder. Change the file to be stored in My Documents or something like that.

Comment: Maybe Debug1.tab isn't where you think it is, try specifying the full path instead and see if that changes anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you specify the file name (without giving a path), the file is created in the current working directory, which may be different from the directory your application resides in. It may help to use the search your disk to see whether the file was created elsewhere.

Anyway: Specify a path when creating the file to make sure it's always in the location where you expect it to be (and do not use the `Program Files` folder, but some publically writable folder).

Comment: I've searched the computer and there are no Debug1.tabs anywhere on the computer.

Comment: Have you tried providing a proper path when creating the file?

Answer (score 0):

you should give full permission to your os curent user on the folder which you are going to write files to .To do that right click on the folder go to properties and go to securitty tab and add the curent user if It does not exist and provide full permission for that user .

Comment: You don't write to the `Program Files` folder from your own applications.

Comment: I know that but I wanted to tell him how he can solve his problem

Comment: Yes, but wouldn't it be better advice to tell him to write to a publically writable folder instead of telling him to mess up permissions? Also: Was it a permission problem, he'd have gotten an exception. He says he didn't, so it's unlikely a permission problem.